# Force img within flexible container to correct ratio

Tags: html, css

The situation I commonly face is that I need to display a set of thumbnails/images that conform to a specific aspect ratio within a flexible container.  The approach I've been using to achieve this is to use a blank, relatively positioned img to *force* the correct aspect ratio, while the *real* image (of unknown ratio) is displayed beneath as an absolutely positioned image.

Example:

```
HTML
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <!-- ordinarily I'd use a transparent PNG, but I'm being lazy... -->
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Placeholder" class="blank-img" />
        <!-- Above img forces correct ratio -->
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" alt="Lookit dah kitty!" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Placeholder" class="blank-img" />
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" alt="Lookit dah kitty!" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Placeholder" class="blank-img" />
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" alt="Lookit dah kitty!" />
    </div>
</div>

CSS
.thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.thumbnail .blank-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0; /* Not necessary for a blank png, but this is easier than importing resources in Fiddle */
}
```

This, in my humble opinion, doesn't seem like a particularly elegant solution.  So my question is this, how can the same effect be achieved without the use of a *blank* PNG or javascript? Also, it should probably go without saying, the images cannot be distorted.

Remember:

1. The image size and aspect ratio is *NOT* known (only the desired aspect ratio is known which, in this instance, is 1:1).
2. The containers themselves are *flexible* in width/height
3. The aspect ratio *must* remain the same (however cropping of the contained image is allowed)
4. No javascript
5. NO JAVASCRIPT.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8W7C/)

Comment: You could just set them as background images and use `background-size: cover`.

Comment: Background-size is not supported by IE8 or lower but if that not an issue for you go with James Donnelly's suggestion.  You may also want to use background-position:center; as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowed from Elastic Videos [example](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos)

Requirements:

- Same desired aspect ratio for all images (all though this can be extended with extra classes)
- Kittens

Markup:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" alt="Lookit dah kitty!" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" alt="Lookit dah kitty!" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" alt="Lookit dah kitty!" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
.thumbnail img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
/* Aspect Ratio 1:1 */
.thumbnail {
    padding-top: 33%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y6Ytz/

If you know all the images are the same height, you can then crop accordingly:

```
/* If you know all the images are the same height */
.thumbnail img {
   top: -50%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LWZY8/

Oh, and it support images of varies heights:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3S5T7/

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, the aspect ratio of the images themselves are not known.  This is effectively a problem arising out of CMS-controlled images (and clients can't be trusted).